# How do I declare a method dynamically with method_missing?

Tags: ruby, closures, metaprogramming

I have a ruby program, and I want to accept the user's made up method, and make a new method out of that name. I have tried this:

```
def method_missing(meth,*args,&block)
  name = meth.to_s
  class << self
    define_method(name) do
      puts "hello " + name
    end
  end
end
```

And I get the following error:

```
`define_method': interning empty string (ArgumentError) in 'method_missing'
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Edit:

I got it working a different way, but I'm still curious how to do it this way. Here is my code:

```
def method_missing(meth,*args,&block)
  Adder.class_eval do
    define_method(meth) do
      puts "hello " + meth
    end
  end
  send("#{meth}")
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The variable `name` is not available inside the class definition (`class << self`) scope. It isn't throwing a NameError because you've overridden `method_missing`.

To do what you're trying to do, you need to keep the scope with `name`. In order to do that, you have to only use block-based methods (e.g. `class_eval`) instead of directly opening the class, so something like this:

```
def method_missing(meth,*args,&block)
  name = meth.to_s
  eigenclass = class << self; self; end
  eigenclass.class_eval do
    define_method(name) do
      puts "hello " + name
    end
  end
end
```

But actually, the symbol in `meth` is quite sufficient — you don't need name at all. (Though you'll still need the above technique either way.) On top of that, though, you want to execute the method immediately. The simplest way would just be to resend the message:

```
def method_missing(meth,*args,&block)
  eigenclass = class << self; self; end
  eigenclass.class_eval do
    define_method(meth) do
      puts "hello #{meth}"
    end
  end
  send(meth, *args, &block)
end
```

Comment: @Aditya Sanghi: Thanks for the correction. But I actually meant to switch to interpolation, which is just all-around better (faster, less garbage, reads cleaner *and* works with symbols!).

Comment: instead of `eigenclass = class << self; self; end` you can simply do - `self.class.class_eval`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `class << self` doesn't act as a closure, which means the variable `name` won't be available inside of the method definiton.

On the other hand, when you use `class_eval`, you're passing a block (`Proc`), which is a closure, which means all of the local variables from the current binding will be available inside the block body.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to define methods dynamically when `method_missing` is called is to call `define_singleton_method`.

```rb
class Person
  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    define_singleton_method(method_name) do
      puts "I'm a new method called #{__method__}"
    end
    # Add this is you want to automatically call the new method
    public_send(method_name)
  end

  # Add this for proper introspection.
  def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private = false)
    true
  end
end
```

This will give you

```rb
Person.new.test_method # => "I'm a new method called test_method"
```

Note: The solution is slightly different to the other solutions proposed, in that it only defines the method on the current instance and not the class. New instances of the same class will not have the newly defined method; but this is usually what people are aiming to do when defining new methods within `method_missing`.